# How to get json value using GSON from json tree

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json such as below

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "status": {
            "statusCode": 0
        },
    },
    "stuff": [
        {
            "name": {
                "text": "red"
            },
            "properties": [
                {
                    "attributes": {
                        "shade": "dark"
                    },
                    "component": {
                        "id": "BA1",
                    }
                    "type": "Color"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": {
                "text": "Toyota Camry"
            },
            "properties": [
                {
                    "attributes": {},
                    "component": {
                        "id": "MS",
                    },
                    "type": "Vehicle"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

I'm using GSON to parse the results like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
JsonObject json = (JsonObject) gson.fromJson(in, JsonObject.class);
System.out.println(json.get("apiVersion").getAsString());
```

I can get the `apiVersion` but don't know how to get elements that are inside the json tree. For example, `type`...what if I want to output all the different `type`..in this case `Color and Vehicle`

Comment: Your JSON string is invalid `}, },` check after statusCode,

Comment: Sorry, I'm just using it as an example to get the point across.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I must be missing something here, but why can't you nest calls to `getJsonObject`? For example, to get the status code:

```
  System.out.println(json.getAsJsonObject("metadata")
                         .getAsJsonObject("status")
                         .get("statusCode").getAsInt());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object in that matter and to parse the json to it (with GSON):

```
ParsedObject parsedObject = new Gson().fromJson(json, ParsedObject.class);

public class ParsedObject {

    @SerializedName(value = "apiVersion")
    private String mApiVersion;

@SerializedName(value = "metadata")
    private Metadata mMetadata;

}
```

Comment: what if i don't want to create a class. I will be using this only for one time use.